# OpenAM as IDP does not redirect back to SP

Tags: authentication, saml, openam

I got a problem with OpenAM. Need your help.

I installed OpenAM and simply configured it as an IDP - set name and circle of trust. Then I added a remote SP by uploading **SP metadata**, see below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EntitiesDescriptor Name="urn:mace:shibboleth:testshib:two" xmlns:shibmd="urn:mace:shibboleth:metadata:1.0" mlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<EntityDescriptor entityID="http://192.168.0.6:8080/employee/">
    <SPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:protocol http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/07/secext">
        <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified
        </NameIDFormat>
        <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress
        </NameIDFormat>
        <AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://192.168.0.6:8080/employee/" index="1" isDefault="true" />
    </SPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor> 
</EntitiesDescriptor>
```

SP and IDP are in the same Circle of Trust.

When I do SAML request for auth from SP to IDP, I get to login page of OpenAM with *SAMLRequest=...* as URL params. Decoded **SAMLRequest** is below

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://192.168.0.6:8080/employee/"
Destination="http://192.168.0.7:8181/openam/" ForceAuthn="false"
ID="ID_479ff8a2-8dc5-44b5-997f-0438a2d87417" IsPassive="false"
IssueInstant="2015-01-07T13:31:01.067Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
Version="2.0">
    <saml:Issuer>http://192.168.0.6:8080/employee/</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient" />
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Then i do login and come to user profile page in OpenAM, instead of redirect to SP. Why it happens? What should I configure to enable redirect back to SP?

Comment: anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you could do:

- Don’t use IP address when installing OpenAM, because cookies will not be saved on such addresses, so you can easily encounter weird problems like this.
- If you have goto URL validation enabled (by default it'd disabled), then there were some old bugs around not handling redirect URLs correctly. Not sure which version you are using, so this may not really apply to you.
- You should capture the network traffic with tools like LiveHTTPHeaders Firefox plugin or similar, so you can see how the HTTP requests go around. That should help you determine where exactly are things going wrong.